# Unable to resolve error in ctx.getContext() in phonegap 3.4

Tags: android, cordova

Here I am tring to call an activity from a phonegap 3.4 plugin and this is the error being shown in the following code.

```
public void startActivity() {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(ctx.getContext(), SecActivity.class);       
        ctx.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
```

"ctx" is showing an error.

But the same code worked with phonegap 1.6.

With what should I replace ctx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ctx is a legacy member and is deprecated since the release of phonegap 2.0.

Check this link http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html

To rectify the error try replacing ctx.getContext() with this.cordova.getActivity()